# Molecule positioning in chemfig reaction schemes

Tags: chemfig

I need to write this reaction scheme:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to place the NADH molecule like it is in the figure. Help me please, thanks!

---

Thanks to Clemens' comment, I've worked out this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
    \chemfig{A}
    \arrow(aa--){0}[-70,.5]
    \chemfig{B}
    \arrow(@aa.mid east--.mid west)
    \chemfig{C}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An example with molecule "A" and "B" would be sufficient! Just to understand the positioning.

Comment: this site already has quite a few examples of using `chemfig`'s schemes. Have you already checked those?

Comment: @clemens Googling this thing mostly returned issues about the anchoring points of schemes, I couldn't find one example of free positioning of a molecule.

Comment: There is no free positioning. Either anchors or invisible arrows. I'm sure the site search for chemfig schemes will return some examples

Comment: My comment only was a comment, really. If there was a specific question and its answers that helped you, I'd rather we close this question as duplicate

Comment: No, I just worked upon your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no free positioning. But with the help of invisible arrows it is not too hard:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{1.8em}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \chemfig{EtO-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30]-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30]}
  \arrow{0}[-60,.4]
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{*6(-N(-R)-=(-(=[2]O)-[::-60]NH_2)-(<:[:70]H)(<[:120]H)-=)}}
    {NADH}
  \arrow(@c1--)
  \chemfig{EtO-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30]-[:-30](<:[6]O|H)-[:30]}
  \+{,,-10pt}
  \arrow(--[yshift=-20pt]){0}[,0]
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{*6(=\chemabove{N}{\scriptstyle+}(-R)-=(-(=[2]O)-[::-60]NH_2)-(-H)=-)}}
    {NAD$^+$}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]